# freeing the popup twice crashes applcation

Tags: delphi, popup

In my execute block that gets called with a button click, I create a popup menu to appear where the button was clicked. It current appears properly, with a few items with one of them having a couple sub items. When this that runs once then calls the destructor, it is fine. But if I execute it twice (show the popup and click an item twice) then destruct, the application crashes. I think it is because I'm not freeing the popup correctly (which is declared as a private property).

```
procedure TPlugIn.Execute(AParameters : WideString);
var
  i: Integer;
  pnt: TPoint;
begin
  GetCursorPos(pnt);

  FPopup := TPopupMenu.Create(nil);
  FPopup.OwnerDraw:=True;
  FPopup.AutoHotkeys := maManual;

  //SQL Upgrade
  Item := TMenuItem.Create(FPopup);
  Item.Caption := 'Database Install/Upgrade';
  Item.OnClick := ShowItemCaption;
  FPopup.Items.Add(Item);

  //Language Folder
  Item := TMenuItem.Create(FPopup);
  Item.Caption := 'Language Folder';
  Item.OnClick := ShowItemCaption;
  FPopup.Items.Add(Item);

  //Machines
  Item := TMenuItem.Create(FPopup);
  Item.Caption := 'Machines';

  MachineItem := TMenuItem.Create(FPopup);
  MachineItem.Caption := 'Sample Machine 1';
  MachineItem.OnClick := ShowItemCaption;
  Item.Add(MachineItem);

  MachineItem := TMenuItem.Create(FPopup);
  MachineItem.Caption := 'Sample Machine 2';
  MachineItem.OnClick := ShowItemCaption;
  Item.Add(MachineItem);


  FPopup.Items.Add(Item);

  Self.FPopup := FPopup;

  FPopup.Popup(pnt.X, pnt.Y);

end;
```

In the `ShowItemCaption` procedure I just show the caption of that sender object. I haven't coded specific events yet. If it free the popup in the execute procedure, the popup doesn't appear anymore.

```
destructor TPlugIn.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
  FPopup.Free;
  //ShowMessage('freed');
end;
```

Comment: You must assign `nil` to your `FPopup` variable (so use e.g. `FreeAndNil(FPopup)`, or `FPopup := nil` after `FPopup.Free` call). This happens because when you call `FPopup.Free` second time, the `FPopup` is just a dangling pointer, but still `Assigned` what makes the `Free` method think there's a valid object behind, thus it calls `Destroy` on that not existing object.

Comment: hmm still the same result as before. it's ok that when i execute twice as use that basically I'm `FPopup` twice and calling `Destroy`? does the second execute call replace the old `FPopup`? I'm just wondering if it's calling `Destroy` for one of the two instances, if that's the case.

Comment: Since you are not telling the whole story here, it is difficult to say what is going wrong. When is TPlugin.Destroy called? Are you using threads?

Comment: Why are you creating it on button click (could happen many times) but freeing it once? You should create your `TPopupMenu` within `TPlugIn.Create`. Otherwise you have some major memory leaks going on here. Not to mention, suppose the popup menu was never even opened. So it was never created in the first place. Then you attempt to free it, but it wasn't created so it will fail.

Comment: @TLama Your advice is incorrect. Looking at the actual code, the title of the question is wrong. The popup menu is created twice and destroyed only once. Furthermore, I am generally opposed to giving that kind of advice even when it would solve the problem because it is too often used as band-aid where the real problem is not understanding & managing instance lifetime correctly.

Comment: @JerryDodge Good advice with one minor quibble: "Then you attempt to free it, but it wasn't created so it will fail." is incorrect. FPopup is a class field, so will be initialised to nil. The whole point of calling `(object).Free` is that `(nil).Free` won't try to Destroy the object.

Comment: @Craig - Where do you see the PopupMenu is created twice?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz His description says: "if I execute it twice (show the popup and click an item twice) then destruct". He can only do this by calling `Execute` twice. Each call creates a new `TPopupMenu` instance.

Comment: @Craig - How do you know the plugin destructor runs only once? Maybe the TPlugin is created per execute and then destroyed.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz That's my interpretation of "execute it twice **then** destruct".

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Furthermore, the given code would not destroy FPopup twice unless he destroys the same TPlugIn instance twice.

Comment: @Craig - OK. You seem to understand what's going on.

Comment: Also "crashes application" is a bit vague. That translates to "the application crashes and fails to continue" but in a VCL Forms Application, only that block of code would crash. The application continues to run technically.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have completely misdiagnosed your problem. As a result you haven't given the information that we need in order to give you a definite solution.

If I take the code you provided, and test it similar to your description: using one button to call the code in the Execute method, and another button to `Free` `FPopup`, I don't get an error. In fact you should try this yourself; you also *shouldn't* get an error; which means that the problem doesn't lie in the code you've provided.

However, that said: I can help you to better diagnose the problem, after which you may be able to solve it yourself - or at least give us better information to help you.
Also you do still have a number of mistakes in this code that **need** to be fixed - even if the mistakes don't cause your application to crash.

---

Let's start by diagnosing the **real** problem. Is your program really ***crashing*** or are you just getting an exception in the debugger? I ask, because it usually requires something a little more extreme to truly **crash** a Delphi application.

If you are just getting an exception, I suspect the debugger is taking you to the line `FPopup.Free;` (Note this is **not** the line where the problem is - the debugger usually takes you to the line ***after***; which would mean the problem is somewhere in the inherited Destroy). ***Also you need to tell us the exception class and message you are getting***.

Either way, even if your application really is crashing, it will almost always be preceded by an exception. And you need to pinpoint exactly where that exception is happening. To do so, you need to:

- Run your application through the debugger.
- Make sure the debugger is set to stop whenever an exception occurs.
- Given that the exception may be happening inside the `TPlugIn` class, make sure that unit is not disabling debug information.
- You might also need to set your project options to "Use Debug DCU's".
- Do your test.

When you get your exception, remember the debugger will usually show you the line after the one that caused the exception. You now need to consider the problem line in conjunction with the error message to figure out what might be going wrong.

If you're getting an *Access Violation*, that is usually because you're trying to:

- Use something that hasn't been created.
- Destroy something that has already been destroyed.
- Use something that has already been destroyed.

To investigate the Access Violation further:

- Identify the problem object.
- Put breakpoints in your code where the object is created/destroyed.
- Run through your code, hitting the breakpoints and figure out what is going on.

---

#### Additional Problems

1. You mentioned that "if you Free the popup in the Execute procedure, it doesn't appear anymore". (Presumably this was your attempt to avoid the memory leak.) This is because when you call `FPopup.Popup(pnt.X, pnt.Y);` it doesn't "pause your code" and wait for an item to be selected. Your code continues running because menus use an event driven model to callback when the item is clicked. Therefore your popup menu would be destroyed, and disappear immediately after it popped up.
2. The line `Self.FPopup := FPopup;` is totally redundant and does nothing. You're effectively saying `FPopup := FPopup` - you're not changing FPopup's value in any way.
3. It should be very obvious that the title "Freeing the popup twice crashes application" is totally incorrect. As per your code and description: you are **creating** the popup twice and freeing it **only once**.
4. That in itself is a problem, because as Jerry pointed out - you have a memory leak. Basically your code overwrites the reference to the first TPopup you created, leaving it "orphaned" and holding onto memory. You then only `Free/Destroy` the ***last*** one created in the TPlugIn destructor.
5. And therein: free the popup before calling the inherited destructor of TPlugIn. It is not neccessary in this case, but normally it is wise to clean up in reverse order of creation.

There isn't (or at least shouldn't be) any need to re-create the popup every time Execute is called. All you should be doing is causing it to popup again with `FPopup.Popup`. This is in fact part of the *point behind making FPopup a private class field*. I.e. you set it up **once** and reuse it as needed.

You could use a technique called lazy-initialisation; but really it's usually an unnecessary complication. You're much better off simply mirroring your creation and destruction of FPopup. I.e. If you *Destroy FPopup when TPlugIn is destroyed* - you should *Create FPopup when TPlugIn is created*.